# How to pass more than one parameter in a Jinja loop?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have two lists:

```
seller = ["Bob", "Joe", "Tim"]
cash = [12, 25, 67]
```

I pass both parameters in the template:

```
...

return render_template("sales.html", sellers=sellers, seller_cash=seller_cash)
```

I want to render both of the parameters in the same loop:

```
{% for seller in sellers %}
  <p><strong>{{seller}}: {{cash}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. Is there a way to have two parameters in the same loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jinja2 does not have an outbox solution to combine both the list transversely but you can leverage the python built-in `zip` to create a list of tuples of individual lists and pass it to jinja template engine.
You also need to re-write your jinja2 loop, such that it can read through a list of tuples

Template invocation

```
return render_template("sales.html", seller_cash=zip(sellers, seller_cash)
```

Jinja2 Loop

```
{% for seller, amount in seller_cash %}
  <p><strong>{{seller}}: {{amount}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, you can the jinja2.Environment global namespace, to make the python `zip` built-in available to jinja2

```
>>> env = jinja2.Environment()
>>> env.globals.update(zip=zip)
>>> tmpl = """{% for seller, amount in zip(sellers, cash) %}
  <p><strong>{{seller}}: {{amount}}</p>
{% endfor %}"""
>>> env.from_string(tmpl).render(sellers=seller, cash=cash)
u'\n  <p><strong>Bob: 12</p>\n\n  <p><strong>Joe: 25</p>\n\n  <p><strong>Tim: 67</p>\n'
```

Comment: Wow. That is perfect. Thanks for explaining!